# When row output is not 6 characters long then show nothing

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL Developer, I don't want to show the value of the row if it's not 6-characters long and basically show null or blank.

I'm trying to use the CASE statement and here's the line:

```
(CASE WHEN ZipCode <6 then null) as Postal_Code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing the *length* of the ZipCode with 6, instead of comparing the ZipCode itself to 6:

```
CASE WHEN length(ZipCode) = 6 then ZipCode end as Postal_Code
```

Syntactic errors corrected too.

Comment: That's exactly what I need and it works! Thank you very much, Bohemian! Much appreciated!